# aiohttp: Вложенные пути RouteTableDef

Tags: python, url, asyncio, aiohttp

Как сделать префиксы путям в `RouteTableDef`, чтобы не дублировать общие части URL? Во Flask для этих целей есть `flask.Blueprint`, в Django `django.urls.include`, а как быть в aiohttp?

Хотелось бы такой код:

```py
from aiohttp import web
routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.get('/api/info')
async def get_info(request):
    ...

@routes.get('/api/obj')
async def get_obj(request):
    ...

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes(routes)
```

Превратить во что-то такое:

```py
from aiohttp import web

routes = web.RouteTableDef()
routes_api = web.RouteTableDef()
routes.append(routes_api, prefix='/api')

@routes_api.get('/info')
async def get_info(request):
    ...

@routes_api.get('/obj')
async def get_obj(request):
    ...

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes(routes)
```

Чтобы можно было вынести описание части путей в отдельный файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В aiohttp нет вложенных путей или префиксов для них, но для этих же целей есть вложенные приложения с префиксами. Получается такой код:

```py
from aiohttp import web

routes_api = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes_api.get('/info')
async def get_info(request):
    ...

@routes_api.get('/obj')
async def get_obj(request):
    ...

app_api = web.Application()
app_api.add_routes(routes_api)

app = web.Application()
app.add_subapp('/api', app_api)
```

Это позволяет легко вынести под-приложения в отдельные файлы. Более подробно см. документацию: [Web Advanced: Nested Applications](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#aiohttp-web-nested-applications)